# Check if row contains a substring, print value in another column (R programming)

Tags: r

**Goal:**

I am looking at example Twitter data and am checking to see if my data in column `"Tweet"` contains the string of words `"yo creo."` If the tweet contains `"yo creo,"` I would like to print a "1" in the column `"Subject Expression"`.

**Error:**

I am receiving the error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.

**Here is my code:**

```
#Read in data
MyData <-read.csv("/Users/mydata/Desktop/MyData.csv")

#Append subject expression column to dataframe
MyData$SubjectExpression <- ""

#Count instances of subject expression using select
MyData%>%
  mutate(SubjectExpression)= 
  case_when(
    select(MyData, Tweet, contains("yo creo") == '1')
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few issues.

- `mutate` syntax is `data %>% mutate(column = value)` - you need to keep the definition of the new column inside mutate's `()`.
- Inside most `dplyr` functions, including `mutate()` you can use column names directly and unquoted. You don't need to `select()` a column (`select()` is for keeping some columns and dropping others)
- `case_when()` argument syntax is `test_1 ~ value_1, test_2 ~ value_2`
- `contains()` is specifically made for column names, to detect the presence a string in a column/vector we'll use `stringr::str_detect`
- `mutate()` can create brand new columns. You don't need to initialize the column with `MyData$SubjectExpression <- ""`. You should just delete that line.

Making all those changes, we get this:

```
MyData%>%
  mutate(SubjectExpression = 
    case_when(
      stringr::str_detect(Tweet, "yo creo") ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for both the solution and the detailed explanation to fix my code! I really appreciate it. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** alternative using `grepl`

```
MyData$SubjectExpression <- grepl("yo creo", MyData$Tweet)*1
```